# Dropping article title in references with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm writing my thesis with TEXstudio using Miktex 2.9 on W7. I want to remove the title in the bibliography output changing from

> Perez-Lombard, L., Ortiz, J., and Pout, C. (2008). A review on buildings energy consumption
>   information. Energy and buildings, 40(3):394-398.

to

> Perez-Lombard, L., Ortiz, J., and Pout, C. (2008). Energy and buildings, 40(3):394-398.

I tryed already severeal method proposed such as changing  to science bibliography style, modifying the apalike.bst style, using makebst etc.. etc... but nothing happened. I think I followed all the available link on the internet but nothing... Please help me!!!

```
\documentclass[twoside]{ecsthesis}      % Use the Thesis Style
\graphicspath{{../Figures/}}   % Location of your graphics files

\usepackage[sort &compress]{natbib}  % Use Natbib style for the refs.\part{title}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Hello World}
Hello World
\cite{perez2008review}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%Biblio
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{ECS}
\end{document}
```

Where the bibliography file ECS.bib is

```
@article{perez2008review,
  title={A review on buildings energy consumption information},
  author={Perez-Lombard, Luis and Ortiz, Jose and Pout, Christine},
  journal={Energy and buildings},
  volume={40},
  number={3},
  pages={394--398},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked for me:

1) make a new style with makebst

2) save it in an appropriate folder (I used a local one) which was already include in miktex roots

3) update the FNDB in miktex

4)Open my .tex file in Texworks

5) pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex

After doing that, new bibliography entry made using texstudio are updated in the new style as well.

So before closing the question can someone tell me: it is a problem of Texstudio which do not compile new style or somelike that?